# Can not import torch

Tags: python, pip

I have installed pytorch using following command

```
pip install --user torchvision
```

But When I try to import it I am getting error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named torch
```

Also it says that all the requirements are satisfied

```
    Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from torchvision) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torch in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torchvision) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.1.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torchvision) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torchvision) (1.14.5)
```

What should I do?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? How did you install pip? Asking cause normally `pip` installs Python 2 packages while `pip3` installs Python 3 packages.

Comment: I'm using pip 10.0.1.  Well the problem is resolved. I was trying importing it in python2  and it was throwing error. I imported it in python3 and it worked. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Visit [torch - PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/torch/).
2. Click the "Download files" link.
3. Clicking the "Download files" link will expose the torch file to download. At the time of posting this answer the name of the torch file is: torch-0.4.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.
4. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   pip3 install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/91/1b2871d6c8ca079254deae5872af32e02e9a85f07dd0834e8b3489ce138f/torch-0.4.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl    
   pip3 install --user torchvision
   ```
5. Start the Python 3 interpreter with the command `python3` and from the python3 prompt type:

   ```
   import torch
   ```