# Package python-software-properties is not available when trying to install Torch

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, python, dpkg

I'm trying to install Torch, but I keep getting this whenever I run the second command on torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html# .The first one works fine however.

```
test@test-VirtualBox~$ cd ~/torch; bash install deps;       
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [79.6 kB]         
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease         
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]            
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic InRelease              
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease                       
Fetched 163 kB in 2s (82.8 kB/s)               
Reading package lists... Done             
Updated successfully.               
Reading package lists... Done                
Building dependency tree             
Reading state information... Done
Package python-software-properties is not available, but is referred to by another package.            
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or        
is only available from another source         
However the following packages replace it:         
  software-properties-common         

E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10. I have literally been using Ubuntu for maybe two days and I have no idea what I'm doing. I've searched everywhere for a while now and I can't find a solution that works, I've tried

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Where are you getting 'torch' from? It sounds like it is not properly set up for 18.10

Comment: torch.ch.                                                   
                                                                            
Like I said I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: You should probably tell the Torch developers that their install script is out of date.

Comment: Well then...uhh

Answer (score 4):

Open the "install-deps" file in Torch folder.
Go to the line 178.
Change `sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties` to `sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common`
Worked for me.

Comment: this one works!

Answer (score 1):

#### Install TensorFlow and PyTorch in Ubuntu 18.04 with CUDA 9.0

1. Check for NVIDIA driver version.

   The first thing you should check is that you have an Nvidia driver installed for your graphics card. Your graphics card must support at least NVIDIA compute 3.0 to install tensorflow-gpu.

   You can check what graphics driver you have installed using `nvidia-smi` .You should see some output like the following:

   ```
   nvidia-smi
   ```
2. Install CUDA Toolkit 9.0.

   Visit https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive and grab the runfile download for Ubuntu 17.04. While this is for a different version of Ubuntu, you can get it to install what you need. You'll have to go to the legacy downloads archive page to find version 9.0. 
   Otherwise you'll need to add ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa to your software sources, run `sudo apt update`, install nvidia-driver-410, and then you can install CUDA Toolkit 10.0 instead of CUDA Toolkit 9.0.

   Click on the following link: [CUDA Toolkit 9.0 Downloads](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1704&target_type=runfilelocal)

   Once you've got that file, navigate to where the file was downloaded in your terminal and check you have the same files as follows:

   ```
   $ ls  
   cuda_9.0.176.1_linux.run  cuda_9.0.176.2_linux.run  
   cuda_9.0.176.3_linux.run  cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
   ```

   Then run the following commands.

   ```
   sudo chmod +x cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run
   ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run --override
   ```

   Accept the terms and conditions, say yes to installing with an unsupported configuration, no to "Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 384.81?".

   Make sure you don't agree to install the new driver. In my experience, doing so often leads to system instability issues. Follow the prompts to install the toolkit using the default install locations.

   Also apply the patches provided.

   ```
   sudo chmod +x cuda_9.0.176.1_linux.run  
   sudo chmod +x cuda_9.0.176.2_linux.run  
   sudo chmod +x cuda_9.0.176.3_linux.run  

   ./cuda_9.0.176.1_linux.run  
   ./cuda_9.0.176.2_linux.run  
   ./cuda_9.0.176.3_linux.run
   ```
3. Install CUDNN 7.1.4.

   You need to login using Nvidia account to download this. Please feel free to signup and then download.

   Visit https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download to get CUDNN 7.1. Go to the downloads archive page again and find version 7.1 for CUDA 9.0 that you just installed. Download the link that says [cuDNN v7.1.4 Library for Linux](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.1.4/prod/9.0_20180516/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.1). This will download an archive that you can unpack and move the contents the correct locations.

   There are lots of options on the archive downloads page for CUDNN. Get the Library for Linux file for CUDA 9.0.

   Once downloaded, unpack the archive and move it the contents into the directory where you will install CUDA 9.0:

   ```
   tar -zxvf cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.1.tgz # unpack the archive
   ```

   Move the unpacked contents to your CUDA directory.

   ```
   sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/  
   sudo cp  cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda-9.0/include/
   ```

   Give read access to all users.

   ```
   sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda-9.0/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
   ```
4. Install libcupti.

   ```
   sudo apt install libcupti-dev
   ```

#### Do the CUDA post-install actions

So TensorFlow can find your CUDA installation and use it properly, you need to add these lines to the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Restart your terminal before proceeding to the next step or do `source ~/.bashrc`

#### Install TensorFlow GPU

Finally to install tensorflow-gpu run:

```
sudo apt install python-pip python3-pip      
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

I recommend installing TensorFlow in a virtualenv to prevent having to muck around with your system Python packages. The [official TensorFlow installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv) give various options, so you can choose what works best for you. If you choose the virtualenv route, I highly recommend using virtualenvwrapper, which makes using virtualenv far easier.

You can now test everything worked by opening a new Python interpreter with `python` and running the following commands:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

If everything worked fine, you'll see your GPU listed as part of the output like this:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 182532294431716449, name: "/device:GPU:0"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 10498270823
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
   links {
     link {
       device_id: 1
       type: "StreamExecutor"
       strength: 1
     }
   }
 }
 incarnation: 14673206105771676974
 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1", name: "/device:GPU:1"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 10917150720
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
   links {
     link {
       type: "StreamExecutor"
       strength: 1
     }
   }
 }
 incarnation: 16384320033882398672
 physical_device_desc: "device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"]
```

[This webpage](https://tools.google.com/seedbank/seeds?keyword=mlbasics) has several interactive TensorFlow tutorials that can execute TensorFlow code in a web browser.

#### Install PyTorch

*Optionally, if you are using pip*

```
pip3 install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/91/1b2871d6c8ca079254deae5872af32e02e9a85f07dd0834e8b3489ce138f/torch-0.4.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl   
pip3 install torchvision
```

If the above link to download torch is broken, update it to the current link by following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052252/can-not-import-torch/1087319#1087319).

You can now test PyTorch by opening a new Python interpreter with `python3` and running the following commands:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()

# True 

import torch
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)

# 'GeForce GTX 1080 Ti'

import torch
torch.cuda.device_count()

# 2
```

<sub>**Source:** updated from [Install Tensorflow , PyTorch in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Cuda 9.0](https://medium.com/@balaprasannav2009/install-tensorflow-pytorch-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-cuda-9-0-for-nvidia-1080-ti-9e45eca99573)</sub>

Comment: Uh...I've already done that, it says                            

software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.27).                 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.